# HTML/Prestashop, moving the category image to the left

Tags: css, prestashop

In the normal prestashop theme, there is a box at the top of the category pages for a description of the category as a whole. The box has an outline and contains a picture and some text.

The text is normally below the image, so the block takes up a lot of room. I would like to float the image to the left, and wrap the text around it, so it's smaller.

I suspected this would be easy, because the image and text are in divs, and both of them are in another div for the outline. So I simply added float:left to the image's DIV.

The image moved to the right OK, and the text flowed too. However, the surrounding DIV did not resize properly, so the image now runs right out of the box.

How do I get the enclosing DIV to resize properly?

Comment: A live link would help, there are numerous versions of ps and numerous themes.

Comment: Indeed, my bad. Try this:

Comment: *sigh* This: http://maurysolar.com/en/solar-panels/ Notice the image flows outside the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to force the containing div to wrap the floated contents. You can do this a few ways, one being to add overflow:hidden.

```
.content_scene_cat {overflow:hidden;}
```